# Building consumable uri/urls for a model (rails/datamapper/SOA)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, uri, datamapper

Perhaps you can help me think this through to greater detail.

I need to build or make available a uri for a model instance that can be referenced or used by another application which may or may not be a rails application.

e.g.

I create a standard Post with content; I want to build a URL for that post another application can consume or reference by looking at the model in the database (or another less sticky fashion). Datamapper has a URI field, I want to build a canonical uri, store it there and have another application be able to access, announce, manipulate, etc.

Basically, I have several applications that may be in different places, that need to access the same model, to do differing things with the model. I need a way to make that happen clearly without putting them all in one monster application.

I've looked at Pubsubhub, RSS, etc. but haven't found any concrete examples of what I'm trying to do. Do I need to create an common API for the applications, etc?

Comment: Yes, this can extend beyond rails, datamapper, or even ruby. I'm trying to wrap my head around SOA/API functions to streamline an application.

Answer (score 0):

DataMapper is very flexible about using existing databases.

Many people come to DataMapper because it can create and tear down the database structures without migrations. However, you do not have to work with it in that way.

I have had good success with using a large set of models owned by a central 'housekeeping' app and then declaring a small subset of the same models in separate 'interface' apps.

Some trial and error is required to figure out what works but it can certainly be done. I'd suggest putting your models in modules and including them across apps if possible.

A final point it sounds like you want URIs/URLs to be the primary interface. If that is the case I strongly suggest you look at Sinatra. It is entirely oriented around URLs (and I find Rails routes very obtuse).